# Connection issues when using newer docker compose versions with Couchbase

Tags: docker, docker-compose, couchbase

Im having trouble setting up a local multimode Couchbase cluster via docker compose.
I am using a docker compose file to setup 3 nodes on my local machine.
It works fine with the old docker compose style but when using newer ones I can't connect to localhost:8091.
Im on macOS using apple silicon (m1).
Im fairly new to docker so I don't really know what could be the issue.
working version:

```
couchbase1:
  image: couchbase/server:community-aarch64
  volumes:
    - ~/couchbase/node1:/opt/couchbase/var
couchbase2:
  image: couchbase/server:community-aarch64
  volumes:
    - ~/couchbase/node2:/opt/couchbase/var
couchbase3:
  image: couchbase/server:community-aarch64
  volumes:
    - ~/couchbase/node3:/opt/couchbase/var
  ports:
    - 8091-8097:8091-8097
    - 9140:9140
    - 11207:11207 
    - 18091-18097:18091-18097
    - 11210:11210
```

not working:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  couchbase1:
    image: couchbase/server:community-aarch64
    volumes:
      - ~/couchbase/node1:/opt/couchbase/var
    networks:
    - proxynet
  couchbase2:
    image: couchbase/server:community-aarch64
    volumes:
      - ~/couchbase/node2:/opt/couchbase/var
    networks:
    - proxynet
  couchbase3:
    image: couchbase/server:community-aarch64
    volumes:
      - ~/couchbase/node3:/opt/couchbase/var
    ports:
      - 8091-8097:8091-8097
      - 9140:9140
      - 11207:11207 
      - 18091-18097:18091-18097
      - 11210:11210
    networks:
      - proxynet
networks:
  proxynet:
    name: custom_network
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind ist actually does Work, it just takes for ages to start up. Even if the containers are running, if you wait for a while it works.